# Data Type Renderers in Intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Recent convert to Intellij.  Eclipse has a feature in the debugger, "Primitive Display Options", which has the debugger render primitives in hex and ascii values.

[image: Eclipse Debugger]

Since everything has been a breeze in Intellij so far, I figured this would be a no brainer, but after an hour and a number of non-functional data type renders later, I find myself ready to crawl back to eclipse.  I made a few renderers that worked, but only for objects, so I can only conclude that renderers seem to not work for primitives.  Can someone point me in the right direction here?

Edit: I've seen the option to select hex in the default render, but I am hoping for something more than a solution that requires 2 clicks for every variable.

Comment: Hmm.  This is an interesting feature of the IDE which I did not know about or care to use until I discovered your question.  I'm going to look into this to see what it can provide.  Although, to be frank, the default view in the debugger for a primitive value is really the best I've seen out there, even after comparing with Eclipse and Netbeans.

Comment: Thanks!  It's invaluable for some of the file format reversing, and ByteBuffer type work I do.  In eclipse, I can inspect a byte array or underlying ByteBuffer and can immediately see ascii or byte patterns in data being read or written.  It's almost makes switching to intellij a non-starter for me.

Comment: Same for me, I really need this functionality for low level debugging. I also fiddled for hours with IntelliJ custom renderers. :-(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For integral values (that is, neither floating-point values nor booleans), you can view them as a hexadecimal value by right-clicking on the primitive in the debugger, and selecting "View As" -> "Hex".

[image]

By default, the Data Type Renderer feature only works with objects, and the only realistic way to represent a primitive is either as its integral value or in hex, so I think this is a happy compromise.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I also found that feature, but I would hate to have to switch it every time I want to see the hex value.  I was even hoping to find something to enable that as default, but failed to find that.

Comment: As much as I don't like it, manual toggling of this feature seems to be the only way I have managed to get this to work.

Comment: @Kyle, see  **Settings** > **Build, Execution, Deployment** > **Debugger** > **Data Views** > **Java** > `"Show hex value for primitives"`

Answer (score 23):

My solution was to provide a custom data type renderer using the following expression for `byte[]`: `new String(Hex.encode(this));`.

This works by default as long as the data type renderer is enabled (maintains state across application restarts, etc.). You can add more elaborate String formatting if you wish (I usually have a utility class which does further formatting and I just invoke it from the DTR expression field).

[image: Data Type Renderer]

[image: Debugger view]

Comment: This is a close solution, but it still is awkward ( mostly unusable for long arrays )

Comment: What library is Hex class from? Couldn't find in rt.jar

Comment: In this case it was probably a custom class that I had written, but any of the hex converter classes from commons-codec or BouncyCastle will work as long as they are on the classpath.

Comment: I have it exactly like in the screenshot but as in the screenshot, byte[] is marked red and intellij complains about unexpected tokens. And in the expression it complains about "this" and claims it is null.

Comment: use `this` keyword. I got it!

Comment: It can be done using a built-in Java class: `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(this);`

Answer (score 4):

There is an option (checkbox) to permanently change all primitives to display as **Hex** under the options for Data Views.  See:

**Settings** > **Build, Execution, Deployment** > **Debugger** > **Data Views** > **Java** >

`"Show hex value for primitives"`

[image]

Answer (score 4):

> I made a few renderers that worked, but only for objects, so I can
>   only conclude that renderers seem to not work for primitives.

With IDEA 2016.3 it's finally possible to define custom Java Data Type Renderers for primitive types (including arrays).

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/#v2016-3

Comment: Using the Java Data Type Renderers for primitive types, I was able to use this expression to view both decimal and hexidecimal values for all ints: this + " [" + String.format("0x%08x", this) + "]"

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to Andy's solution, but does not require you to define the `Hex` class (which he even does not mention). Only works for Java8 projects (that is, not on Android currently).

You have to provide a custom data type renderer using the following expression for `byte[]` (see [Andy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376692/952135)):

```
IntStream.range(0,Math.min((this.length+3)/4,20)).mapToObj(i->IntStream.range(i*4,Math.min(i*4+4,_this.length)).mapToObj(i1->String.format("%02x",_this[i1])).collect(Collectors.joining())).collect(Collectors.joining(" "))+(this.length>80?"...":"")
```

It will format the data such that "01020304 05060708 09", i.e. grouped by four and separated by spaces. Only first 80 bytes are displayed, ellipsis is added if there are more.

Comment: The Hex class he is refererring to is probably the one from Shiro or one of the apache-commons projects, something a lot of projects already have on the classpath.

Comment: This didn't work for me: Unable to evaluate expression Lambdas evaluation is not supported

Answer (score 2):

You can also try [DeltaHex Editor plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9339) for IntelliJ based IDEs which can show window with typical hex + text preview for byte array in debugger.

[image: DeltaHex Editor Plugin Debug Byte Array Image]

Plugin is available in Settings/Plugins/Browse repositories/Search for DeltaHex