# How to use Data Type Renderers list for byte[] in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-13

So I have all these byte[]'s, and their encoding could be one of many different formats, depending on where I'm currently debugging.  I'd like to be able to toss together a list of projections for the byte array.  I'm using IntelliJ's Data Type Renderers view, applying the renderer to type byte[], and I'm primarily concerned with the List of Expressions box.

So I've seen how you can render the node with the expression `new String(this)`, however that doesn't work in the list of expressions view below.  Eventually I want to do expressions like `new String(this, "UTF16")` (or do conversions to hex or base64 or w/e) but `this` doesn't appear to be a byte[] in the expressions list box - in fact, when I try to typecast like `(byte[])this` the result says `Inconvertible types; cannot cast '_Dummy_.__Array__≤T≥' to 'byte[]'` (same behavior for java.lang.Byte[]).  It's really strange behavior, that in one place it's a byte[] and in another it's some opaque internal type.

What does work is simply displaying the fields - i.e., an expression like `this.length` works as expected.  Also, an expression like `this` simply rerenders the node, claiming its type is byte[] and its object id is the same as the original's id.

Comment: It almost sounds like Idea is trying to auto box the type and is failing. Can you add to the question what happens if you try manually boxing the primitives in java.lang.Byte[] and re-evaluating the expression?

Comment: Added some detail.  There's no conversion from _Dummy_.__Array__<T> to any java.lang type that I'm aware of :-).

Answer (score 0):

I answered a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376692/70465). The message about being unable to cast `_Dummy_.__Array__<T>` to `byte[]` sounds like an IntelliJ error where it can't determine the name of the class in the call stack. Perhaps adding DTRs for other "forms" of `byte[]` will help. I've included examples of three DTRs below -- `byte[]`, `Byte[]` and `ArrayList`.

The test and the helper method (written in Groovy, so make sure it's on your classpath or rewrite in pure Java):

```
@Test
void testShouldHandleDTR() {
    // Arrange
    byte[] primitiveArray = "90abcdef".bytes
    Byte[] objectArray = "90abcdef".bytes
    List<Byte> objectList = "90abcdef".bytes

    final String EXPECTED_STRING = Hex.encodeHexString(primitiveArray)
    logger.info("Expected hex string: ${EXPECTED_STRING}")

    // Fully qualified for DTR dialog
    String primitiveDTR = "org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex.toHexString(this);"
    String objectArrayDTR = "org.example.ThisTest.encodeObjectArrayToHex(this);"
    String objectListDTR = "org.example.ThisTest.encodeObjectArrayToHex(this.toArray());"

    def types = [primitiveArray, objectArray, objectList]
    def expressions = [(primitiveArray.class.name): primitiveDTR,
                       (objectArray.class.name): objectArrayDTR,
                       (objectList.class.name): objectListDTR]

    // Act
    types.each { it ->
        logger.info("Contents: ${it}")
        logger.info("Type: ${it.class.name}")

        String result = Eval.x(it, expressions[it.class.name].replaceAll(/this/, "x"))
        logger.info("Result: ${result}")

        // Assert
        assert result == EXPECTED_STRING
    }
}

public static String encodeObjectArrayToHex(Object[] objectArray) {
    byte[] primitiveArray = objectArray.collect { it as byte }
    Hex.encodeHexString(primitiveArray)
}
```

For each DTR you want to define, just copy the exact String defined above into the **When rendering a node > Use following expression** field. I'd recommend putting the utility method into a source class on your classpath as opposed to a test, as on every build you will have to re-import the test class in the DTR dialog because the `target/` gets cleaned.

[image: Successful test execution]

[image: DTR for ArrayList in action]